# Add Image.file to Photos Favorites album from within Flutter app

Tags: image, flutter, photo-gallery, camera-roll, image-file

Is it possible to favorite an image in the Apple and Android photo app within my flutter app?

For example, if my app accesses many images from the camera roll/gallery using the multi_image_picker plugin and I have the Image.file location can I add it to the Favorites album in Apple Photos for inside my app? Same for Android or Google photos?

Answer (score 0):

Accessing native gallery app features isn't possible as those features are built for the specific app only. You can create all of those features for your app but you can't access features of other apps into your flutter app.